# How to circumvent using an out parameter in an anonymous method block?

Tags: c#, anonymous-methods, out-parameters

The following method does not compile. Visual Studio warns "An out parameter may not be used within an anonymous method". The `WithReaderLock(Proc action)` method takes a `delegate void Proc()`.

```
public Boolean TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value)
{
    Boolean got = false;
    WithReaderLock(delegate
    {
        got = dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value);
    });
    return got;
}
```

What's the best way to get this behavior? (Please refrain from providing advice on threadsafe dictionaries, this question is intended to solve the out parameter problem in general).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value)
{
    bool got = false;            
    TValue tmp = default(TValue); // for definite assignment
    WithReaderLock(delegate
    {
        got = dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out tmp);
    });
    value = tmp;
    return got;
}
```

(edited - small bug)

For info, in .NET 3.5 you might want to use the `Action` delegate instead of rolling your own, since people will recognise it more. Even in 2.0, there are lots of `void Foo()` delegates: `ThreadStart`, `MethodInvoker`, etc - but `Action` is the easiest to follow ;-p

Comment: Sorry for the glitch in the original version; fixed

Comment: I see `delegate void Action<T>(T obj)` in .NET 2.0, but that operates _on_ an object. I need operations _around_ an action. Hence, the `delegate void Proc()`. I could name it `delegate void Action()` to be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is to just copy the logic inside the method. But then we stretch the DRY principle and have to maintain behavior inside both methods.

```
public Boolean TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value)
{
    internalLock.AcquireReaderLock(Timeout.Infine);
    try
    {
        return dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value);
    }
    finally
    {
        internalLock.ReleaseReaderLock();
    }
}
```