# How do lambda expressions work internally?

Tags: c#, lambda, anonymous-methods

While looking up the answer to this question: "[Why is an out parameter not allowed within an anonymous method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637863/why-is-an-out-parameter-not-allowed-within-an-anonymous-method)" I've got a little lost about how do lambda expression and anonymous methods actually work.

In the comments JaredPar states that "Imagine for instance that the out parameter referred to a local variable on the stack. The lambda can execute at any arbitrary point in the future and hence could execute when that stack frame was no longer valid".

I pointed out if wouldn't that be the case with any other variable... which basically make me wonder what to I really know about lambda expressions.

The thing I have in mind is something like this:

```
public void Foo(ComplexObject val, out SomeDelegate outDelegate)
{
  ComplexObject obj = new ComplexObject(val)
  SomeDelegate = delegate(int other) { return (obj.value * other); }  
}

public void Bar()
{
  SomeDelegate MyDel = null;
  Foo(5, out MyDel);
  int finalRes = MyDel(100);
  // Whatever
}
```

In that situation I don't really know what's happening. obj is a reference on the stack which would no longer be valid on method return so the annonymous method should be able (if that works) to actually know that's a reference type and copy the reference instead of the value, if it does... why wouldn't ref params work if the "use case" is more or less the same?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did a fairly extensive blog series on how closures work internally.  It's written for the VB.Net implementation of closures but the underlying details are very similar to C#'s.  It should provide the answers you're looking for

Here is the link to part 6 which links to all of the other articles

- http://blogs.msdn.com/jaredpar/archive/2007/08/06/closures-in-vb-part-6-limitations.aspx

Answer (score 6):

Jon Skeet wrote an [in-depth description](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/csharp2/delegates.html#anonymous.methods).

Basically, the compiler turns the outer method into a class, and turns all of the variables that are accessed by the anonymous methods into fields on the class.  The anonymous methods become regular instance methods on the class.