# How do I make a streaming LINQ expression that delivers the filtered out items as well as the filtered items?

Tags: c#, linq, enumeration, out

I am transforming an Excel spreadsheet into a list of "Elements" (this is a domain term). During this transformation, I need to skip the header rows and throw out malformed rows that cannot be transformed.

Now comes the fun part. I need to capture those malformed records so that I can report on them. I constructed a crazy LINQ statement (below). These are extension methods hiding the messy LINQ operations on the types from the OpenXml library.

```
var elements = sheet
    .Rows()                          <-- BEGIN sheet data transform
    .SkipColumnHeaders()
    .ToRowLookup()
    .ToCellLookup()
    .SkipEmptyRows()                 <-- END sheet data transform
    .ToElements(strings)             <-- BEGIN domain transform
    .RemoveBadRecords(out discard)
    .OrderByCompositeKey();
```

The interesting part starts at `ToElements`, where I transform the row lookup to my domain object list (details: it's called an `ElementRow`, which is later transformed into an `Element`). Bad records are created with just a key (the Excel row index) and are uniquely identifiable vs. a real element.

```
public static IEnumerable<ElementRow> ToElements(this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<UInt32Value, Cell[]>> map)
{
    return map.Select(pair =>
    {
        try
        {
            return ElementRow.FromCells(pair.Key, pair.Value);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return ElementRow.BadRecord(pair.Key);
        }
    });
}
```

Then, I want to remove those bad records (it's easier to collect *all of them* before filtering). That method is `RemoveBadRecords`, which started like this...

```
public static IEnumerable<ElementRow> RemoveBadRecords(this IEnumerable<ElementRow> elements)
{
    return elements.Where(el => el.FormatId != 0);
}
```

However, I need to report the discarded elements! And I don't want to muddy my transform extension method with reporting. So, I went to the out parameter (taking into account [the difficulties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384918) of using an out param in an anonymous block)

```
public static IEnumerable<ElementRow> RemoveBadRecords(this IEnumerable<ElementRow> elements, out List<ElementRow> discard)
{
    var temp = new List<ElementRow>();
    var filtered = elements.Where(el =>
    {
        if (el.FormatId == 0) temp.Add(el);
        return el.FormatId != 0;
    });

    discard = temp;
    return filtered;
}
```

And, lo! I thought I was hardcore and would have this working in one shot...

```
var discard = new List<ElementRow>();
var elements = data
    /* snipped long LINQ statement */
    .RemoveBadRecords(out discard)
    /* snipped long LINQ statement */

discard.ForEach(el => failures.Add(el));

foreach(var el in elements) 
{ 
    /* do more work, maybe add more failures */ 
}

return new Result(elements, failures);
```

But, nothing was in my `discard` list at the time I looped through it! I stepped through the code and realized that I successfully created a fully-streaming LINQ statement.

1. The temp list was created
2. The `Where` filter was assigned (but not yet run)
3. And the discard list was assigned
4. Then the streaming thing was returned

When `discard` was iterated, it contained no elements, because the elements weren't iterated over yet.

Is there a way to fix this problem using the thing I constructed? Do I have to force an iteration of the data before or during the bad record filter? Is there another construction that I've missed?

### Some Commentary

Jon mentioned that the assignment /was/ happening. I simply wasn't waiting for it. If I check the contents of `discard` after the iteration of `elements`, it is, in fact, full! So, I don't actually have an assignment problem. Unless I take Jon's advice on what's good/bad to have in a LINQ statement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> When the statement was actually iterated, the Where clause ran and temp filled up, but discard was never assigned again!

It doesn't need to be assigned again - the existing list which will have been assigned to `discard` in the calling code will be populated.

However, I'd *strongly* recommend against this approach. Using an `out` parameter here is really against the spirit of LINQ. (If you iterate over your results twice, you'll end up with a list which contains all the bad elements twice. Ick!)

I'd suggest materializing the query *before* removing the bad records - and then you can run separate queries:

```
var allElements = sheet
    .Rows()
    .SkipColumnHeaders()
    .ToRowLookup()
    .ToCellLookup()
    .SkipEmptyRows()
    .ToElements(strings) 
    .ToList();

var goodElements = allElements.Where(el => el.FormatId != 0)
                              .OrderByCompositeKey();

var badElements = allElements.Where(el => el.FormatId == 0);
```

By materializing the query in a `List<>`, you only process each row once in terms of `ToRowLookup`, `ToCellLookup` etc. It does mean you need to have enough memory to keep all the elements at a time, of course. There are alternative approaches (such as taking an action on each bad element while filtering it) but they're still likely to end up being fairly fragile.

EDIT: Another option as mentioned by Servy is to use `ToLookup`, which will materialize and group in one go:

```
var lookup = sheet
    .Rows()
    .SkipColumnHeaders()
    .ToRowLookup()
    .ToCellLookup()
    .SkipEmptyRows()
    .ToElements(strings) 
    .OrderByCompositeKey()
    .ToLookup(el => el.FormatId == 0);
```

Then you can use:

```
foreach (var goodElement in lookup[false])
{
    ...
}
```

and

```
foreach (var badElement in lookup[true])
{
    ...
}
```

Note that this performs the ordering on *all* elements, good and bad. An alternative is to remove the ordering from the original query and use:

```
foreach (var goodElement in lookup[false].OrderByCompositeKey())
{
    ...
}
```

I'm not personally wild about grouping by true/false - it feels like a *bit* of an abuse of what's normally meant to be a key-based lookup - but it would certainly work.

Comment: Another option would be `allElements.ToLookup(el => el.FormatId == 0);` Then you can just get the true/false value from the lookup for the good/bad items, but that would also materialize the whole query.

Comment: Hey, you're right about the assignment working! The problem was where I was checking the `discard` list. I'm updating the question to that effect. Thx for the answer, lots to chew on.

Comment: @Servy, please write that up as an answer with some more sample code. I'm interested.

Comment: @AnthonyMastrean I fail to see what other code would be needed beyond what I've already posted; and it's not going to be functionally different from Jon's code (unless the `Where` predicate were expensive, as I avoid computing it twice, but in this case it's not,).

Comment: @Servy, it's ok, I guess you have enough rep? I just saw your comment as an answer and thought you'd like to promote it. Thanks, Jon, for writing it up.

Comment: It's funny, Jon Skeet answers your question and no one else even bothers ;)